# Firefox hangs with Java in Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, google-chrome, java-applet

I am using Firefox 3.6 on Linux and I have Java 6 update 15. Obviously I am using the newer plugin type.

Whenever I open a page with a Java applet it just becomes unresponsive and hangs. I tried with Chrome. I think it detects the Java plugin from Mozilla's plugins folder. Due to the multiprocess architecture it doesn't hang and shows the initial applet loading window but then it reports that the plugin has crashed.

The only way I can run Java applets is to download the class file and make an HTML file and run the applet using applet viewer.

Edit: I am here adding a crash report and this shows that there is problem with native system libraries: http://pastebin.com/mcL1MRHD.

Comment: Your pastebin crash report appears to be from running Java via the Mozilla plugin via the Chrome browser, yet your question your question title is about Firefox and Java.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest following [these instructions](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Using+the+Java+plugin+with+Firefox) from Mozilla about installing and testing / verifying your Java installation.

Also ensure that you don't have an older version of Java installed and running by mistake (such as Java 5 or Java 6 prior to Update 10), because Firefox 3.6 requires [Java 6 Update 10](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/firefox_newplugin.xml).

View `about:plugins` and look for `libnpjp2.so` or the Java plugin and see what version it is trying to run.

Comment: My Java plugin is libnpjp2.so and the version is Java(TM) Plug-in 1.6.0_15 . Of course I made it clear in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clearer, I've seen installations with multiple JRE versions installed, and so it isn't always obvious that the newest JRE is the only that the browser is configured to use.